# In MS Word, how to move a word or selection to the right or left?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, selection

I know how to select a word or phrase with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→ Right Arrow</kbd> or character wise with <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→ Right Arrow</kbd>.

My question is: How do I move a selection within the text, within the paragraph, to the left or right? The stepping could be per character, or better, per word.

[image: Move WORD4 to the end]

Answer (score 4):

There's no shortcut to move texts like that. You may need to use VBA for that purpose

However if *multiple* keystrokes are allowed then you can use Word's *Move To* function like this

- Select the text you want to move
- Press <kbd>F2</kbd>
- Press <kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> to move the cursor to where you want to move the text
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Yes it's not much better than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, move then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

[Here's the complete shortcut list](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-for-microsoft-word-on-windows-95ef89dd-7142-4b50-afb2-f762f663ceb2)

Answer (score 1):

To move text in Word, you can use either the following two methods:

- Select the text, click <kbd>F2</kbd> (then move the cursor and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
- Select the text, directly drag and drop it to the wanted location by using mouse.

Comment: The first option does not seem to work for me. I am looking for a way to do it without the mouse, as it disrupts my typing even more.

Comment: If so, I am afraid no keyboards to directly achieve it...

Answer (score 0):

Without putting my hand on the mouse, my best keyboard move is

- Select word
- Cut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
- Move around per word <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>arrowkeys</kbd>
- Paste <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Hope that helps. (:

Comment: to cut you need to use Ctrl+X, not Ctrl+C

Comment: Yup, you're right. Thanks for the heads up. ( :